# How can I get SSL certificates from traefik + lets encrypt for client

Tags: mysql, traefik, emqx

I'm currently working on securing the connection to my EMQX broker by mqtt and websocket and MySQL database. However it's required for the apps the TLS server certs (I mean that) in format domain.crt, domain.key and domain.ca and I couldn't resolve it from dumping my acme.json from traefik to chain.pem, fullchain.pem, cert.pem and privkey.pem; maybe I don't get some basics in these terms but it's extremely difficult to get information especific about CA cert online.

If anyone has a clear idea how I can get these three files in that structure it would be grateful. I must to say that I have running other docker containers with full SSL support just as you see in  https://calderasinecolma.com with a wildcard certificate in previous metioned acme.json format

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Why use the same certs for the mtls as for the website?  Why not instead use something like [https://cert-manager.io/docs/](cert-manager) to generate your certificate and key, and configure your python pods to use those?

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved just using the fullchain.pem and privkey.pem skipping the cacert.pem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).